# PHP Problem - When inserting </ to the database it renders as a code

Tags: php, mysql, database

Hey,
I own http://ilikeyou.tk/ which is a facebook like website.
Basically, users can add a phrase and/or a photo and like it on facebook.
Recently, when I tested a few stuff I found out that when I insert `</` 
in the text box and create the page, it messes up with the like list.
(You can try posting `</` and going back to homepage, scroll down to 'Recent Like' and watch it)
In sites like twitter and facebook, this stuff never happen.. so there might be a solution..
Any suggestions?

P.S;
Also, when i try to insert the photo link (http://profile.ak.fbcdn.net/hprofile-ak-snc4/188178_139794909415037_3755895_n.jpg) the whole index page goes down (I can still go to like pages like ilikeyou.tk/1/ but cant access ilikeyou.tk ... ).
When deleting the link from the database its all working fine again.

P.S2; 
Sorry for my bad English

Thanks in advanced.

Comment: Please use comments under individual answers to ask for more clarification.

Answer (score 6):

You need to call `htmlspecialchars` on all data coming from your database before displaying it on your page. Failure to do so not only causes problems such as the one you see, but it is also a big security issue: it allows *cross-site scripting* (XSS) attacks on your application.

So if you have `$phrase` coming in from anywhere (not only your database), it's wrong to do this:

```
echo $phrase;
```

You have to do this instead:

```
echo htmlspecialchars($phrase);
```

You can search SO or Google for "XSS" or "cross site scripting" for more information.

Answer (score 0):

Well of course. I could also be inputting this into your text field:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    window.location = 'http://mysite.com';
</script>
```

This would steal all your visitors and send them to my site.

**You cannot trust user input**. Ever. And you should never trustingly insert user input into other content unsanitized. I hope you're at least aware of [SQL injection](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SQL_injection)?

For output into HTML, you can either remove anything that looks like a tag using [`strip_tags`](http://php.net/strip_tags) or escape characters that have a special meaning in HTML using [`htmlentities`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.htmlentities.php). Possibly you should use a mix of both.